# Error de conexión en nodejs y sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

estoy comenzando un proyecto en nodejs y debo conectar mi app a una base de datos en sql server.  Usando tedious estoy haciendo la conexión, pero me da error y no encuentro cómo resolverlo.
Mi código:

```js
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        userName: 'usuario',  
        password: 'clave',  
        server: 'direccionipservidor', 
        port: '1433', 
        options: {
            database: 'BBDD'
        }  
    };  
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function (err) {
        var Request = require('tedious').Request;
        request = new Request("SELECT * FROM roles;", function (err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
            }
        });
    
        request.on('row', function (columns) {
            columns.forEach(function (column) {
                console.log(column.value);
            });
        });
    
        connection.execSql(request);
    });
```

El error:

```
C:\Users\mporras\api_node>node consulta.js
ERROR
{ RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the 
  SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state at RequestError   
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:32:12)
at Connection.makeRequest 
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1678:24)
at Connection.execSql 
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1457:10)
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mporras\api_node\consulta.js:31:20)
at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Connection.message 
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1972:18)
at Connection.dispatchEvent 
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1172:36)
at MessageIO.messageIo.on 
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1045:14)
at MessageIO.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Message.message.on 
(C:\Users\mporras\api_node\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:32:14)
message:
'Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the 
SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state',
 code: 'EINVALIDSTATE' }
```

Revisé las credenciales de conexión y están correctas, son las mismas que utilizo para conectar un sistema web en laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo por acá la solución que encontré por si alguien mas se le presenta el mismo problema.
El asunto es que nodejs con la dependencia tedious se conectará directamente al servidor de base de datos, no se conecta directamente a una base de datos. Para acceder a las tablas, en el select, se debe especificar  database.esquema.tabla

```js
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {
    server: 'dreccionipdelservidor',
    authentication: {
      type: 'default',
      options: {
        userName: 'user',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }
};  
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        // If no error, then good to proceed.  
        console.log("Connected");  
        executeStatement();  
        
    });  
  
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
     
    function executeStatement() {  
        request = new Request("SELECT * FROM database.esquema.tabla;", function(err) {  
        if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });  
        var result = "";  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                result+= column.value + " ";  
              }  
            });  
            console.log(result);  
            result ="";  
        });  
  
        request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
        
        });  
        connection.execSql(request);  

        
    }
```

Comment: Si, con sql server es una buena practica usar el formato `database.esquema.tabla`

Answer (score 0):

Para dejar en la conexión la base de datos que quieres debes agregar bajo la opción `options` la propiedad `database: 'base_de_datos'` como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

Nota: Uso DOT ENV para ocultar los "Secretos" (claves, token, entre otros)

```
  const config = {
    server: process.env.SERVER,
    options: {},
    authentication: {
      type: "default",
      options: {  
        userName: process.env.USER_SQL,
        password: process.env.PASS_SQL,
        database: process.env.BD
      }
    }
    ,options: {
        database: process.env.BD,
      }
  };
```

Ya con esto no es necesario que indiques la base de datos en la consulta.

Saludos!

Comment: podrías agregar una explicación de lo que hace tu código?

Comment: Hola @Riaven, el codigo que muestro solo esta enfocado a la configuracion de la conexión a la base de datos. Utilizo Dot Env (`process.env` + el nombre de la variable) para ocupar los datos que no se deben compatir (claves, token, usuarios, etc).